# How is CrmSvcUtil.exe different from SvcUtil.exe

Tags: dynamics-crm

Would someone be able to explain why Microsoft needed released a separate executable to generate proxies for Dynamic CRM hosted services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly because `crmsvcutil.exe` is able to generate the `OrganizationServiceContext` class (parameter `/servicecontextname`), that is specific to Dynamics CRM implementation.